# IOS5 and Safari 5 for Windows AJAX POST request issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, ios5, safari

```
function updateTemplate()
{   

    var data = $("#create_template").serialize();


     $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/show_config.php",
        async: true,
        cache: true,
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            $("#current_config").html(data);
        }

      });

}
```

This Function works with all Browsers i own in Android or Windows except Safari 5 for Windows and some IOS Versions.

It seems that the request isn't submitted to the PHP script and the Display Updates the data.

are their known bugs for Apple Products and AJAX?